# add options to option menu with the same command as all the others

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu, tkinter.optionmenu

Hi im trying to add options to an option menu depending on how many options the user wants, I haven't included the user input part because it isn't necessary in solving the problem. I want all the options in the option menu to call the class `optionshow` but for some reason i cant get it working please help.
Here's the code, thanks for any help in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

class optionshow:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.p = p.get()
        print(self.p)

option = tk.StringVar()
option.set('Select')
optionmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, option, 'Select', command=lambda: optionshow(option))
optionmenu.place(x=350, y=20)

choices = ('12345')
for choice in choices:
    optionmenu['menu'].add_command(label=choice, command=tk._setit(option, choice))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does `command=lambda: optionshow(option)` do?

Comment: it calls the class ```class optionshow```

Comment: That's made no sense.the argument of `command` shouldn't be a `class`.

Comment: You can use a class in the argument command, i've done it many times

Comment: But why would you want to call a class?I don't know what's your purpose.

Comment: so it can print the value selected

Comment: and obviously theres more code i need to put in there, but i made a minimal example

Comment: If you only want to print the selected value,but why don't consider to use a function directly?It will waste unnecessary overhead(time and space).Do you have any other requirements?

Comment: It's a pointless to discuss whether or not a class should be instantiated with command= . In itself, it is entirely valid to instantiate a class. The class might have much more functionality than in the example above. But even if not, it is a personal preference to use it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate the class only for the 'Entry' option (and not correctly). Why don't you take a different approach and add all the options at once while creating the menu:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

class optionshow():
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.p = p.get()
        print(self.p)

option = tk.StringVar(root)
option.set('Select')
choices = ('12345')
optionmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, option, 'Select', *choices, command=lambda x: optionshow(option))
optionmenu.place(x=350, y=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Note the necessary correction in the `command=lambda` part.

Comment: thankyou very much, this is what i was trying to do, what does the 'x' in command=lambda x: do

Comment: It can be any variable name. If you leave it out, you will get an error message that lambda takes no arguments. However, you specify option as a parameter, so you need to give lambda an argument to take that parameter.